# CarrierWave : No error triggered when file type is on blacklist in test:unit

Tags: ruby, upload, carrierwave

```
def upload_fixture_file filename, content_type
    ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new({
      :filename => filename,
      :content_type => content_type,
      :tempfile => File.new("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/files/" + filename)
                                           })
end

test "should deny exe file upload" do
  file = upload_fixture_file 'SkypeSetup.exe', "application/exe"
  assert_no_difference 'Upload.count' do
    post :create, :upload => { :case_id=> cases(:fred_and_oliver_open).id, :file     => file, :reviewed => :false, :user_id =>   users(:fred).id }
  end
end
```

Running the test above yields "Upload.count" didn't change by 0. On my app I get the expected "An error occurred : File You are not allowed to upload "exe" files, allowed types: ["jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "pdf", "doc", "docs", "rtf", "ods", "bmp", "odt"]"

Why is this happening?
Thank you